# Set file.endWith method from a list of string when setting File filter

Tags: java, android-layout, arraylist

I am trying to set file filter with this method

```
 public void setFileFilter(final long maxSize, final String extensions) {
    this.maxSize = maxSize;
    this.expectedFormat = extensions;
    this.formatsArray = expectedFormat.split(",");
    this.e = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(formatsArray));

    fileFilter = file -> ((file.isDirectory()) || (file.getName().contains(".")
            && (file.length() <= (maxSize * 1024))
            && e != null && e.contains(file.getPath().substring(file.getPath().lastIndexOf(".")))));
}
```

I am getting the extension from the backend in a String Array which I split and put in an ArrayList. the issue is that the files are not listed. but when I use the `file.endsWith()` method  like this

```
public void setFileFilter(final long maxSize, final String extensions) {
    this.maxSize = maxSize;
    this.expectedFormat = extensions;
    this.formatsArray = expectedFormat.split(",");
    this.e = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(formatsArray));

    fileFilter = file -> ((file.isDirectory()) || (file.getName().contains(".")
            && (file.length() <= (maxSize * 1024))
            && (file.getPath().endsWith(".jpg") || file.getPath().endsWith(".jpeg") || file.getPath().endsWith(".pdf"))));
}
```

for all of the extensions we support it works well, but I don't want to hardcode the extensions. I want to be able to check if the extension from the file matches any string in the array list. Please any help on how to achieve this?

Comment: Does your string containing extensions [A] contain the `.` and [B] contain zero spaces? e.g. `".xls,.xlsx"` is good, anything else would not work. If you want to dodge the spaces, split on `"\\s*,\\s*"` instead just `","`.

Comment: You were right. There was some spaces in between. Everything works fine. Thanks